# How to create this step-by-step shape to showcase a process flow

Tags: css, wordpress, customization

I tried googling everywhere but could not find a plugin or any css tutorial to make this boxes-shaped section to illustrate a process flow?

My client insist on having it in that shape.

Please see the attached picture. 
[this is the screenshot of the section i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYHfI.jpg)

That section is in this website http://www.oaktreeclinicmidlands.co.uk/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interesting CSS shape navigation (chevrons)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036841/interesting-css-shape-navigation-chevrons)

Comment: Can you help me with a css code? I dont know which part of the css is responsible of the pointy right thing. I am not soo good at css or programming in general. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combining `display: flex;` and SVG, you can get a responsive design that scales to any viewport without referencing external images.

This snippet uses two flexboxes on top of each other, one with the SVG elements and one with the copy. The background colors of the first two SVG elements match the `fill` attribute of the succeeding elements to achieve scalable spacing without overcomplicating the CSS.

Happy coding!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #26353D;
}

.arrow-item {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.arrow-1 {
  fill: #F29720;
  background-color: #99BB64;
}

.arrow-2 {
  fill: #99BB64;
  background-color: #5EA02B;
}

.arrow-3 {
  fill: #5EA02B;
}

.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  padding: 100px;
}

.text-item {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
  <svg class="arrow-item arrow-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 724 668"><polygon points="668 668 0 668 0 0 668 0 724 334 668 668"/></svg>
  <svg class="arrow-item arrow-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 724 668"><polygon points="668 668 0 668 0 0 668 0 724 334 668 668"/></svg>
  <svg class="arrow-item arrow-3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 724 668"><polygon points="668 668 0 668 0 0 668 0 724 334 668 668"/></svg>
</div>

<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text-item">
    <h2>Consultation</h2>
    <p>Contact us if you are struggling with any mental or emotional health issues, We will arrange.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-item">
    <h2>Treatment</h2>
    <p>Treatment starts with assessment of your issues with comprehensive care planning. Care plan could.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-item">
    <h2>Support</h2>
    <p>Recovery- With a friendly and approachable team of clinicians and administrative staff.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Karson Kalt. I really really appreciate it. You are the best.
Can I ask? I can understand from your answer that this is already responsive but when i resize my screen it does not respond.? should i be doing something ... please forgive me I am a noob

Comment: What you're going to find with this particular design is that there is a point where the design will break, meaning the text will no longer be able to be represented in a row. What I would do is build a media query breakpoint where the flexbox is changed from `flex-direction: row;` to `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: There is a great article on flexbox on [CSS Tricks] (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you so much Karson ... your answer is so helpful .I will implement it and then let you know of the result